# Best method to create low poly version of a complicated mesh?

Tags: workflow

I'm making this train in blender, which I will export later on into unreal engine. But I need to create a low poly version of it. Its around 200k tris at the moment in total, which seems like a lot for a game asset. Its a complicated mesh with many separate parts. So I don't want to go through every single part and try to make a low poly of each piece... I feel like there might be another way? So is there a method for doing it more quickly?

[image]
Cheers

updated results from decimate and limited disolve----

[image]

Comment: you probably can delete manually some edge loops that don't seem very useful, other than that you have tool like X > Limited Dissolve (and you can tweak the angle in the Operator box) or in the Object Data panel > Remesh, or the Decimate modifier, but these tools can be unpredictable...

Comment: also try the different options of Decimate

Comment: Ive just tried both - please check above - updated results from decimate and limited disolve---- They both give good results but both of them produce alot of Ngons - probably because of my bad mesh haaha.  I dont know how to fix those Ngons. Any ideas?

Comment: There's an addon called Instant Mesh, maybe you should give a try: https://blender-addons.org/instant-meshes-remesh/

Comment: Actually the guy says that the internal Remesh tools are good, he also cites Auto Remesher: https://blender-addons.org/open-source-auto-remesher/

Comment: I tried remesh but it went crazy. Il try the addons, thanks!

Comment: How can I install that addon?

Comment: I think that Remesh > Voxel works pretty good, you need to set the good Voxel Size (in units). I don't know these addons, to install, find the page, download the zip, do not unzip, open Edit > Preferences > Addon, click on Install and activate

Comment: There's also an addon called retopoflow that might help.  It is really helpful for making video game assets especially.  However, it is a paid addon, $86.00 to be exact.  But if you are willing to spend some money, I would very highly recommend it.   Here's the link if you want to check it out:https://blendermarket.com/products/retopoflow